# How to test RSK testnet deployed smart contracts via Hardhat?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, hardhat, rsk

I am using Hardhat to deploy and test my smart contract on RSK testnet. This is the `hardhat.config.js` setup I am using:

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');

const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync('.mnemonic', 'utf8').toString().trim();
const minimumGasPriceTestnet = 65164000;
const TESTNET_GAS_MULT = 1;
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.7.3',
  defaultNetwork: 'rsktestnet',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      gasPrice: Math.floor(minimumGasPriceTestnet * TESTNET_GAS_MULT),
      gasMultiplier: TESTNET_GAS_MULT,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic,
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 10,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Unfortunately, my tests fail and I receive the following error message:

```sh
Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/ales/Work/IOV/demo-code-snippets/hardhat-tutorial/ethers-waffle/test/Token.js)
          at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
          at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

What is the problem here? What does `done()` referring to here?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are deploying to a public blockchain network,
need to take into account the block mining interval.
On the RSK network, this takes around 30s.
Mocha, which is the test runner framework used by hardhat,
fails when tests take longer than 20s.

The solution is to configure Mocha to use a longer timeout value,
before it fails tests for taking too long.
Here's the [reference hardhat config documentation](https://hardhat.org/config/#json-rpc-based-networks).

Add the following lines to your `hardhat.config.js`,
if you wish to set a timeout of,
for example, 10 minutes (60000ms).

```js
mocha: {
    timeout: 600000,
},
```

---

And the full `hardhat.config.js` file should look as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.7.3',
  defaultNetwork: 'rsktestnet',
  networks: {
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      gasPrice: Math.floor(minimumGasPriceTestnet * TESTNET_GAS_MULT),
      gasMultiplier: TESTNET_GAS_MULT,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic,
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 10,
      },
    },
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 600000,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645658/194982) configures hardhat such that you can set the **default** timeout for all tests. This may be sufficient in some cases; however in others, we may need to vary the duration allowed with higher granularity.

To do this, use `this.timeout()` within `describe` blocks or `it` blocks. For example:

```js
describe('(1) my group of test with no blockchain interactions', function () {
    it('(1a) my simple test', function() {
        // this gets 2s (the mocha default)
    });
});

describe('(2) my group of rsk tests', function () {
    // each `it` block within this describe block gets 35s
    this.timeout(35e3); 

    it('(2a) my rsk test with 1 transaction', function() {
        // this gets 35s
    });

    it('(2b) my rsk test with 3 transactions', function() {
        this.timeout(105e3); 
        // this gets 105s
    });
});
```

In the above example, we have:

(1) the first `describe` block.

(1a) the `it` test gets the default mocha timeout of 2s.

(2) the second `describe` block,
which configures a custom timeout of 35s.

(2a) the first `it` test,
which "inherits" the 35s custom timeout from its parent `describe` block.

(2b) the second `it` test,
which "overrides" the 35s custom timeout from its parent `describe` block,
and instead sets its own 105s custom timeout.